# Is there a Microsoft.Net.Compilers equivalent for C# 7.0?

Tags: asp.net, c#-7.0

When C# 6 arrived I just referenced the [Microsoft.Net.Compilers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/) NuGet package and TFS builds of C# 6 features started working right away without having to install additional dependencies on the build machine.

Now that C# 7 is here is there an equivalent NuGet package that can do the same thing? (or is this not really a recommended way of adopting C# 7?)

The description for the Microsoft.Net.Compilers package does say that it "causes the project to be built using the specific version of the C# [...] compilers contained in the package", however I can't find out what the corresponding C# compiler version is for a given NuGet package. I've tried adding the latest stable version (1.3.2) however C# 7 features aren't compiling (and this package is ~6 months old anyway, so I wouldn't really have expected it to work)

Comment: Have you tried the pre-release versions? 2.0.0-rc4 that was released in February, for example?

Comment: @MarcGravell No I hadn't, that tells me I need MSBuild v14.0 or above. I guess either way I'm going to need to make some changes to the build machine

Comment: @Justin did you get .Net Compilers 2 working on your build machine?  If so how, I can't get past the 'need MS build 14' error

Answer (score 5):

An updated [Microsoft.Net.Compilers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/) package was published the same week that VS2017 was released.

See the [Roslyn documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/NuGet-packages#versioning) about what package version corresponds to which C# language version.